# pysnmp-make agent side for sending needed traps

Tags: agent, pysnmp, snmp-trap

I already write my trap receiver program for get traps but now I want to write custom agent for my servers which send traps to trap receiver
but the sample is too poor and can't help me much. sample is:

```
from pysnmp.carrier.asyncore.dispatch import AsyncoreDispatcher
from pysnmp.carrier.asyncore.dgram import udp, udp6, unix
from pyasn1.codec.ber import decoder
from pysnmp.proto import api


# noinspection PyUnusedLocal
def cbFun(transportDispatcher, transportDomain, transportAddress, wholeMsg):
while wholeMsg:
    msgVer = int(api.decodeMessageVersion(wholeMsg))
    if msgVer in api.protoModules:
        pMod = api.protoModules[msgVer]
    else:
        print('Unsupported SNMP version %s' % msgVer)
        return
    reqMsg, wholeMsg = decoder.decode(
        wholeMsg, asn1Spec=pMod.Message(),
    )
    print('Notification message from %s:%s: ' % (
        transportDomain, transportAddress
    )
          )
    reqPDU = pMod.apiMessage.getPDU(reqMsg)
    if reqPDU.isSameTypeWith(pMod.TrapPDU()):
        if msgVer == api.protoVersion1:
            print('Enterprise: %s' % (pMod.apiTrapPDU.getEnterprise(reqPDU).prettyPrint()))
            print('Agent Address: %s' % (pMod.apiTrapPDU.getAgentAddr(reqPDU).prettyPrint()))
            print('Generic Trap: %s' % (pMod.apiTrapPDU.getGenericTrap(reqPDU).prettyPrint()))
            print('Specific Trap: %s' % (pMod.apiTrapPDU.getSpecificTrap(reqPDU).prettyPrint()))
            print('Uptime: %s' % (pMod.apiTrapPDU.getTimeStamp(reqPDU).prettyPrint()))
            varBinds = pMod.apiTrapPDU.getVarBinds(reqPDU)
        else:
            varBinds = pMod.apiPDU.getVarBinds(reqPDU)
        print('Var-binds:')
        for oid, val in varBinds:
            print('%s = %s' % (oid.prettyPrint(), val.prettyPrint()))
return wholeMsg


transportDispatcher = AsyncoreDispatcher()

transportDispatcher.registerRecvCbFun(cbFun)

# UDP/IPv4
transportDispatcher.registerTransport(
udp.domainName, udp.UdpSocketTransport().openServerMode(('localhost', 162))
)

# UDP/IPv6
transportDispatcher.registerTransport(
udp6.domainName, udp6.Udp6SocketTransport().openServerMode(('::1', 162))
)

## Local domain socket
# transportDispatcher.registerTransport(
#    unix.domainName, unix.UnixSocketTransport().openServerMode('/tmp/snmp-manager')
# )

transportDispatcher.jobStarted(1)

try:
    # Dispatcher will never finish as job#1 never reaches zero
    transportDispatcher.runDispatcher()
except:
    transportDispatcher.closeDispatcher()
    raise
```

I need my agent send up-time, temp, CPU usage, RAM usage and etc

Comment: You should get all the variable-bindings your agent sends in the TRAP message as `varBinds`. You will find all OIDs and their values in that list.. So you can walk the list, extract the OIDs you are interested in and process the values as you need to. What exactly is your concern?

Comment: I can do walk my server to give all OIDs but what I concern is about how can this program which I wrote is correct and can give traps send from server. it's about work with trap/info not OIDs

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand your concern here. I am trying to say that `varBinds = pMod.apiPDU.getVarBinds(reqPDU)` will give you the `list` of `(oid, value)` objects as they were sent by your SNMP agent. You can iterate over `varBinds`, compare each `oid` with the known ones and do something about its `value`.